# Can the re-usability concept be applied to css?

Tags: css, oop

I was just checking out [this page](http://www.slideshare.net/stubbornella/object-oriented-css), and came across the fact that CSS can be OO(Object oriented). So, is it possible to apply the re-usability concept of OOPs to css? If yes then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly OOP but using Sass, in particular its mixins and variables, will help to reuse your CSS.

http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about CSS being OO, after all it's not even Turing-complete.
As for Sass, it bring complexity to what should remain, imho, a simple static set of rules.

But you can definitely achieve reuse-ability with CSS. Avoid CSS rules related to an ID, as they're not reusable, avoid big CSS definitions with everything from margins to backgrounds to font syle, create short CSS rules that define simple behaviors, then combine these rules by applying multiple classes to your HTML elements like `<span class="big emboss red">`. Each of these rules has a simple and obvious meaning and can be reused.

Comment: However, classes like you've used in your example (.big, .emboss, .red) don't say anything about the content. CSS classes should describe content (.important, .contact_information) and NOT appearance. Since the error message that is red today (.red) could be orange in the next iteration of the website.

Comment: In an ideal world, Damien, you would be right... However, I've noticed that often, web designers don't think like this, and what is ".emphasized" could be red on the left of the page, green on the right, blue on Monday and orange in January... More often than not, after having fought my boss, the designers, and lost all fights  because I'm just the coder, I find it convenient to tag a ".red" instead of implementing a ".left .monday .emph{color:red}"

Answer (score 2):

A good thing to write well structured and reusable css is http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not really OO in the sense of OOP, but yes, you can reuse CSS. I've used the OOCSS methodology in situations where I'm working with larger development teams on longer ongoing projects. We try to establish a base CSS framework and then build upon that using the OOCSS.

Pros:

- developers, with a bit of documentation, can reuse the CSS without having to constantly come back to a UI designer to create new classes for them
- should be easier to maintain long term
- typically leaner CSS files (as you avoid doing one-off classes more than typical)

Cons:

- you tend to have more classes in your markup class attributes
- it's not semantic
- everyone managing the CSS has to be on board and understand the concepts related to it (else you end up mixing your OOCSS with a bunch of one-off classes and end up with a bigger mess)